# Allow/restrict access based on privacy setting flags in profile

Tags: users, flags

I have privacy profile type and flags with checkbox like "Keep all my friends private" and "Keep all my videos and channels private".These are in my privacy settings profile.Now i want  to allow or restrict the access based on my flagging (on/off checkbox) for the users.Here i have two content types videos & channels.By default other users can watch my videos & channels and i want to make it private when i click my checkbox on for "Keep all my videos and channels private" and once i uncheck this,it should become public.The same need to be done for "Keep all my friends private".I have used user relationship module for friends.How can i do this? Is it possible using php coding or is there any other solution.Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to use hooks. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7

Comment: Have tried using Rules?

Comment: using rules, you can play with the profile visibility with the user roles. If user click "Keep all my videos and channels private", add a role "Private" (for example), and then define permissions for this role. When unchecking "Keep all my videos and channels private" => remove role "Private".

Comment: Actually channel(node) page shouldnot be visible to users if the author has checked the profile flag "Keep all my channels private"(profile flag) in his privacy settings.I am tring with hooks but not getting how to check whether the flag "Keep all my channels private"(flag is of type profile) is flaged and based on that access is restricted.How to create a hook for this?

Answer (score 1):

Implement `hook_node_access($node, $op, $account)` and check whether the user has flagged his content to be private, if so then deny access.

```
function MYMODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account){
  global $user;

  if($node->uid != $user->uid && $node->type=='video' && $op=='view'){
     $entity_type = 'profile2';
     $profile = profile2_load_by_user($node->uid,'main');

     $flagging_data = flag_get_user_flags($entity_type, $profile->pid ,$node->uid);

     /************ UPDATED ****************/
     if(isset($flagging_data['channels'])){
          return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But i am still not able to get specific flag as i have many flags in my privacy profile.So, how to get the specific profile flag (e.g."Keep all my videos and channels private") in the above code?

Comment: The function will return all the flags associated with the entity for the user, so assuming you have two flags named `videos,channels` then if you want to check channels then see the updated answer.

Comment: I have updated the changes but not able to save the module having the above code.I have enabled the module & when i try to save the same,getting whitescreen.How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you made any other changes, the code couldn't have caused the issue, check your PHP log.

Comment: function videoprivacy_node_access($node, $op, $account){
  global $user;

  if($node->uid != $user->uid && $node->type=='video' && $op=='view'){
     $entity_type = 'profile2';
     $profile = profile2_load_by_user($node->uid,'privacy');

     $flagging_data = flag_get_user_flags($entity_type, $profile->pid, $node->uid);

    if(isset($flagging_data['my_videos_private'])){   
    return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
     }
  }
}  This is the code which i have used in my module,but getting whitescreen while saving the module. How can i fix it?

Comment: check your PHP log